# WVD (Windows virtual desktop) vs HVD (hosted virtual desktop)

Tags: virtualization, azure-virtual-machine

Hopefully this is correct group to ask that question...
What is the difference between HVD technology and new WVD?  My understanding both run in the cloud, provide simplified centralized management, and both support RDS (Remote Desktop Services).
So what is different and what are the advantages of new WVD vs. "old" HVD?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Hosted Virtual Desktop (HVD) often referred to as a cloud-hosted virtual desktop, is an interface that delivers applications and data that are stored on a cloud provider’s servers instead of the user’s computer or corporate network also it's known as [Desktop as a Service (DaaS)](https://3tallah.com/category/azure/windows-virtual-desktop-wvd/) so this is the delivery model or technology, but both are the same, just Microsoft created its own ([WVD](https://3tallah.com/category/azure/windows-virtual-desktop-wvd/)), like Citrix as well they have another Daas called Citrix Managed Desktops